# Tizen Studio: Multi-package (Hybrid) application is impossible now?

Tags: tizen-studio

I have Tizen Studio 4.6.

Already created a Tizen5.5 wearable **native GUI app**, and a **native service app**. Now I wish to bundle them together, for easier installation.

However Tizen Studio always give me a non-informative error:

[image]

So, then how am I supposed to create the multi-package?

Comment: If I replace "native gui app" to "web gui app", it works, but I don't want to create web app, I want to use native gui app.

Answer (score 0):

In my case of me, I tested it on TizenStduio 5.0
It works fine.
I can make multi-package of wearable 5.5(basicui + service app)
When I see your image, I think that you did not install fully sdk.
Could you install the sdk again?
Thanks